# How to reference children from firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

### **Problem**

I am trying to get a list of comments from a post in a basic social media app I am making. I pushed a couple of comments to a post, and am trying to retrieve them as a list by the original post's key. I am using this code, and I'm not getting anything:

```
getItems(){
var items = [];
var query = ref.child(this.state.passKey).orderByKey();
query.once ('value', (snap) => {
  snap.forEach ( (child) => {       
   items.push({
     comment: child.val().comment,
 });
 });
}).then(() => {
    this.setState({firebaseItems: items});
});
}
```

Ref being refrencing the list of posts on firebase, and passKey being the key from the post I am trying to grab the comments from.

**Firebase Layout**

```
posts:
    -Kzeruiwnpirnwreo:
        content: 'random post example'
        -Kzoreipwrnipgierwn:
            comment: 'comment example'
        -Kzqipeurpireroei:
            comment: 'another comment example'
```

Comment: You should try adding an error callback as the third argument in `once()` –
 you could be getting a permission error or something. Also `console.log()` inside the callbacks so you can see what is being called and what isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass both a callback into `one()` **and** implement `then()`. It has to be one or the other. Luckily it's quite easy to modify your code to only use one:

```
getItems() {
    var query = ref.child(this.state.passKey).orderByKey();
    query.once('value').then((snap) => {
        var items = [];
        snap.forEach((child) => {
            items.push({
                comment: child.val().comment,
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            firebaseItems: items
        });
    }).catch((error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```